# DaemonDisappearedException after upgrading Android gradle Plugin to 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

As mentioned in the title, I am getting the error in Android Studio
Details of the stacktrace are as below

Error which I am facing on CI/CD pipeline.

```
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:249)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:222)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:184)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:147)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:98)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:275)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:247)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:240)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

Other details:
Kotlin version: `1.5.31`
Gradle version : `7.1.1`